# How to extract first number between comma in each line with python

Tags: python, regex

I have this input

> xxxx,123456,sometext123456,123456,anothertext,123,a

and it is repeated again in first of each line (**that is sample of a big log file**).

Now I want to extract just first number (`123456` after the `xxxx`) of each line. I tried this regex

```
(?<=,)[^,]+(?=,)
```

but it's not working for my needs.

Comment: Did none of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+extract+word+from+string) help?

Comment: will the number be always after the first comma?

Comment: yes , numbers will be always after the first comma

Comment: @alireza71: Then you may simply do `my_string.split(',')[1]`

Comment: Will the numbers always be directly after the first comma though?

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri  i can't use split because it is just a small part of log file.

Comment: @alireza71 you read the log file by lines, then `split()` will work perfectly.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri i can't because word merge together in log file and I avoid to do it.

Comment: read file using `file.readlines()` and `split` it for each line

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri  i used already file.readlines() , i don't use split because i have many comma in one line,for example i see one line of log in 15 line of a 15 inch screen :D(i mean it's very long!).

Comment: @alireza71 if the length of each chunk between comma in your string is fixed, you may use *string slicing*. Even if it is not fixed, I will say *split* is better than *regex*

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri thanks with a lot of apologize  , it;s work for me string.split(',')[1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex: [**`^.*?(\d+).*$`**](https://regex101.com/r/DbqORI/2), in which group 1 matches the first number after start of the line. Don't forget multiline flag so `^` and `$` also matches start and end of a line.

```
matches = re.finditer(r"^.*?(\d+).*$", input, re.MULTILINE)
for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    print("n = " + match.group(1))  # Group 1 matches the number
```